# Text id like youtube, is it encrypted or just a random string?

Tags: url

A lot of website using these type of GET id, such as `www.mywebste.com/?id=ABDXC5Z` instead of `www.mywebste.com/?id=30` I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. What is the benefit of doing this? Is it for preventing auto-crawling that can get everything from the website?
2. How to implement it? Is the ID just a unique random string store in the database, or the encrypted data that can be decrypted to normal id?
3. If I store unique string index as ID, does that really affect the performance of my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that this might be used. Most likely, the system is auto-generating a random ID (from a hash or something similar) instead of a sequential one to prevent collisions or to allow simultaneous generation by multiple servers behind a load balancer. The ID isn't "encrypted", it's just an arbitrary key that the server uses to look up the resource in some sort of database.

Comment: Thanks chrylis, then it's no different if I generate more meaningful ID like mysite.com/?v=a-meaingful-id, which is based on, say, content title, is that right?

Comment: Probably. There's no way to say for certain, but most likely not.